# Groovy: run SQL SELECT LIKE from file with params

Tags: sql, select, groovy

The groovy code is

```
import groovy.sql.*
dbUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://server'
dbUser = 'username'
dbPassword = 'password'
dbDriver = 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
sql = Sql.newInstance(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword, dbDriver)
def sqlfromfile = new SqlFromFile()
sqlfromfile.sql_filename='select_query.sql'
sqlfromfile.read()
try{
     def result = sql.rows(sqlfromfile.result,[id:'01'])
     println result
}catch(e){
     println e
}

class SqlFromFile {
    def sql_filename
    def read(){
        result= new File("sqlfolder/"+sql_filename).text
        return result
    }}
```

It's working fine with sql file:

```
SELECT  * FROM [db].[dbo].[TABLE] WHERE [ID] = :id
```

But if I try make LIKE SELECT

```
SELECT  * FROM [db].[dbo].[TABLE] WHERE [ID] LIKE %:id%
```

I've got an error `Incorrect syntax near '@P0'`
Is there is a way to resolve this problem?

Comment: If `id` is numeric (as ids often are), why would you want to use `like`?

Comment: sometimes I need to select id's started from first chars, like: SELECT * FROM `TABLE` LIKE  `01%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT  * FROM [db].[dbo].[TABLE] WHERE [ID] LIKE '%'+convert(varchar(50),:id)+'%'
```

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The data types nvarchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator.

Comment: how I can replace `[db]` variable in sql file?

Comment: You can use replace function like this replace('abcd','a','q')

Comment: I mean change scrip like `SELECT  * FROM '['+convert(varchar(50),:db)+']'.[dbo].[TABLE] WHERE [ID] LIKE '%'+convert(varchar(50),:id)+'%'` when I do this, I've got an error com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '['.

Comment: It is not possible. all query to make single string and pass